Why does the shell run remaining input when the char *buf is larger than size_t count for a read system call?
I ran into a little bug or unexpected behaviour in x86-64 assembly on my Linux machine.
In the .bss section I'm reserving 16 bytes in memory which I call name
When the user enters their name, it will be output back onto the screen with a hello message. However when the user types in something that is larger than 16 characters, the rest of the characters will be immediately run in the console.
The issue
Is this what people refer to as a buffer overflow? But why is the code after 16 characters being run in the first place? I thought that the application would crash or simply not work. Where is the rest of the message being saved to and how does it happen that my shell which is zsh runs especially that code?
I'm sorry if these questions sound silly, but i just started yesterday with assembly language and im trying to understand what the linux kernel is doing.

The full source code for my program is this:
section .data
    question1   db "What is your name? "
    greeting    db "Hello, "

section .bss
    name        resb 16     ; Reserve 16 bytes in memory for "name"

section .text
    global _start           ; define at which label (address) the main program routine should start

_start:
    call _printQuestion
    call _getName
    call _printGreeting
    call _printName
    
    ; Define the next syscall to end the program
    mov     rax, 60         ; ID for sys_exit syscall
    mov     rdi, 0          ; rdi = errorcode value. 0 = No error
    syscall             ; run the syscall to exit

_getName:
    mov     rax, 0          ; Syscall 0 for sys_read
    mov rdi, 0          ; Standard Input
    mov rsi, name       
    mov rdx, 16
    syscall
    ret

_printQuestion:
    mov     rax, 1
    mov rdi, 1
    mov rsi, question1
    mov rdx, 19
    syscall
    ret

_printGreeting:
    mov     rax, 1
    mov rdi, 1
    mov rsi, greeting
    mov     rdx, 7
    syscall
    ret

_printName:
    mov rax, 1
    mov rdi, 1
    mov rsi, name
    mov rdx, 16
    syscall
    ret

I knew that the program would do unexpected things, but I wasn't expecting this and i want to understand if this is a common issue and how to fix it.

You're reading 16 characters from the terminal. When the program exits, everything after that is still in the keyboard buffer, and it gets read by the shell. Then it executes it.

You should keep reading until you get a newline if there's no newline in name.

So i understand this correctly, i should rather loop through the memory, one character after eachother until i hit a 0xA and then stop it? how would i do the name resb [byte count] then if i dont really know how many bytes a user would input?
Like i already know the address of "name" so i would do something like
loop:
mov rax, 1
mov rdi, 1
mov rsi, name+rdx ; memory address of the first character, 2nd pass memory address + 1 Byte for the next character
mov rdx, 1 ; get the first byte from memory address at name
syscall

First check if 0xA is in name. If not, go into a loop that calls read 1 character at a time until you get a newline.

Something analogous to the C loop while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF)

You still need somewhere to put the characters you're reading.  But unless you want to learn about memory management right now, you'd be better off just using a much bigger buffer.

yes i will use a bigger buffer for now and just read until 0xA, i was just interested in why this happens in the first place :D

The part of your question about "dynamically" calculating sizes of static things (actually just automatically at build time to avoid hard-coding it in multiple places) is unrelated so I edited it out.  See How does $ work in NASM, exactly?

This is happening because your program doesn't necessarily read an entire line of input. If the user enters a line longer than 16 characters, you read the first 16 of them. The rest stays in the terminal driver's buffer, and it will be returned in the next call to read(). When your program exits, the shell calls read() to get the next command line, this will return the remainder of the input line, and the shell then executes it.

now it makes sense, because i was telling the sys_write syscall to load rsi with the memory address and rdx with a value, the shell will just continue reading at rsi's memory address at offset rdx and the \n then comes from hitting enter when the program asked me to enter a name, so it will immidiately run afterwards.

When your program finishes, its memory is gone. The shell doesn't read from that memory address. It calls read() to get input from the terminal. The terminal driver in the kernel has the rest of the input line in its memory.

i suppose this is a feature from the linux kernel? I was also wondering how linux or windows manages it so that one program cant access the memory of another program, is there a name for this concept so i could do some research on it?

That's part of the virtual memory system.
